# Unterminated string literal issue with script

Tags: javascript

I'm testing script on latest firebug enabled firefox. The script below gives error message. You can see error message's screenshot below.

[image]

on firebug

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(L) {
        if (typeof(ar_cn) == "undefined") ar_cn = 1;
        var S = 'setTimeout(function(e){if(!self.CgiHref){document.close();e=parent.document.getElementById("ar_container_"+ar_bnum);e.parentNode.removeChild(e);}},3000);',
            j = ' type="text/javascript"',
            t = 0,
            D = document,
            n = ar_cn;
        L = 'http:' + L + escape(D.referrer || 'unknown') + '&rnd=' + Math.round(Math.random() * 999999999);

        function _() {
            if (t++ < 100) {
                var F = D.getElementById('ar_container_' + n);
                if (F) {
                    try {
                        var d = F.contentDocument || (window.ActiveXObject && window.frames['ar_container_' + n].document);
                        if (d) {
                            d.write('<sc' + 'ript' + j + '>var ar_bnum=' + n + ';' + S + '</sc' + 'ript><sc' + 'ript' + j + ' src="' + L + '"></sc' + 'ript>');
                            t = 0
                        } else setTimeout(_, 100);
                    } catch (e) {
                        try {
                            F.src = "javascript:{document.write('<sc'+'ript" + j + ">var ar_bnum=" + n + "; document.domain="" + D.domain + "";" + S + "</sc'+'ript>');document.write('<sc'+'ript" + j + " src="" + L + ""></sc'+'ript>');}";
                            return
                        } catch (E) {}
                    }
                } else setTimeout(_, 100);
            }
        }
        D.write('<div style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;left:-1000px;position:absolute;"><iframe id="ar_container_' + ar_cn + '" width=1 height=1 marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 scrolling=no frameborder=0></iframe></div><div id="ad_ph_' + ar_cn + '" style="display:none;"></div>');
        _();
        ar_cn++;
    })('//ad.adriver.ru/cgi-bin/erle.cgi?sid=1&ad=481915&bt=43&pid=1722467&bn=1722467&tail256=');
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Whatever it is that you are doing, it looks very evil.

Comment: How did you expect this to ever work? `src = "javascript:` JavaScript as a protocol is a bad idea, `{` You're not making an object, so why is this here? `"; document.domain=""` You've got a badly quoted string there, `document.write` Please don't use document.write, especially not on a timeout(this will just break the page after a random timer, which sounds like idiotic behaviour).

Answer (score 5):

Stop it. Whatever it is you are doing.

- Your code is not fooling anyone. It's an ad injection script and if it were on my site I would remove it had I wanted to.
- Your code is unmaintainable and impossible to follow.
- Your code looks very suspicious and might be blocked by various services and adblockers.

Stop trying to be smarter than your browser and than your users.

```
<script>
    (function(link) {
        var el = document.createElement("script");
        el.src = link;
        document.body.appendChild(el);
    })('//ad.adriver.ru/cgi-bin/erle.cgi?sid=1&ad=481915&bt=43&pid=1722467&bn=1722467&tail256=');
</script>
```

Comment: script that you provided, what's for?

Comment: TypeError: document.body.append is not a function

Comment: appendChild he meant

Comment: This is not meant to be copy/paste code. This code will append the ad script element to the page. Anything else you need to do. No one here will sit and teach you JavaScript from scratch.

Comment: your code didn't fix anything

Comment: @demonoid That would be because it's not supposed to - it simply clearly shows to readers of this question exactly what you're trying to create.